# where do i add an if statement into my program to find a certain number

Tags: c, if-statement

I have a program where six numbers are input into an array then output them backwards and if the number 26 is found print found 26. my problem is I think i have my if statement in the wrong place because no matter what i input into the array it prints found 26. Can someone help me and tell me what i did wrong?
      #include

```
        int main ()
        {
          int array[6];
          int x;
          int number=26;

         printf("Enter six numbers.\n\n");

         for(x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
         printf ("Enter a number : ", x+1);
         scanf ("%d",&array[x]);

        if (number=26);
        {
          printf("FOUND 26!"); 
        }

       }

      for(x = 6; x > 0; x--)
    { 



       printf("The numbers backwards are:");
       printf("%d\n", array[x- 1]);

     }


      return 0;
     }
```

Comment: 1. Comparison requires double `==` 2. remove the semi-colon after `if`: `if (number=26);` -> `if (number==26) {`.

Comment: You assing 26 to `number`, then never use that variable again until the if statement (which is an assignment in your code as well). Of course it will print out "FOUND 26".

Comment: @victoriatibbs  Just say instead of the computer: "Found!" and do not use any if statement.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These statements

```
    if (number=26);
    {
      printf("FOUND 26!"); 
    }
```

can be equivalently rewritten like

```
    if (number=26) /* null statement */;

    // separate compound statement
    {
      printf("FOUND 26!"); 
    }
```

Moreover in the condition of the if statement there is used assignment `number=26` instead of comparison `number == 26`.

And one more moreover if you will write comparison and remove the semicolon like this

```
    if (number == 26)
    {
      printf("FOUND 26!"); 
    }
```

the statement does not make sense because evidently `number` is equal to 26 because it was initially initialized such a way.

I think you need to output the message when the array is outputted in the reverse order. The code can look like

```
     const int N = 26;

     printf("Enter six numbers.\n\n");

     for(x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
     printf ("Enter a number : ", x+1);
     scanf ("%d",&array[x]);
    }

   printf("The numbers backwards are:");

   for(x = 6; x > 0; x--)
   { 
       printf("%d\n", array[x- 1]);
       if ( array[x-1] == N )
       {
          printf( "FOUND %d!\n", N ); 
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using: `if (number == 26)` instead of `if(number = 26)`.

The first one is a comparison while the second is an assignment which always returns True.

Also, you have an erroneous `;` after the `if`

Comment: thank you i changed the code its still saying found 26 enter a number

Answer (score 1):

You have used `if (number=26);`. What you should be using is `if(number == 26)`

The `=` is an assignment operator, whereas the `==` is a comparison operator.

Using a `;` after an if statement is wrong as the compiler considers it as an empty statement.